# How to apply Gaussian kernel to smooth density of points on 2D (algorithmically)

Tags: normal-distribution

I have a set of points on a 2D surface and need to build a heatmap. However, I also need to smooth out the density/distribution by applying some sort of kernel (Gaussian kernel, for example).

I Know what Gaussian distribution is, and I have no idea, how mathematically apply the Gaussian kernel to the points on 2D so I can get a smooth distribution or density of points. I know there are functions in Wolfram to do that, but this is more like a research problem, so I need to understand how this is done.

Can someone, please, explain to me mathematically how this is done, and possibly with an example? Or take me to a website that I can read about it?

I'd much appreciate that.

Thanks

Comment: Cross-posted to the stats site: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/113078

Answer (score 1):

Since the points are discrete, you simply translate the kernel to each point and scale it by the height (value) at that point, and then sum the results.

$f(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}{p_{i,j}f(x-x_{i},y-y_{j})}$

where $f(x,y)$ is your kernel and $p_{i,j}$ is the value of the point at $(x_{i},y_{j})$

Comment: Hi, This looks like what I need. Is there any documents I can read about more details of this process? For example, a document that explains why this becomes smooth in the end, and still maintain a good level of information of the original distribution before applying the kernel?

Comment: @simo: It is smooth because it is a finite sum of smooth functions.

Comment: Hi Nate. If we multiply the height at each point with f(x−xi,y−yj), does it affect the density at all? Say, if f(x−xi,y−yj) > f(x−xp,y−yq) for two particular points (xi,xj) and (xp,xq), then this would change the relative original densities at (xi,xj) and (xp,xq). I think I am wrong, but cannot understand why I am wrong. Maybe it's something in the function f(x−xi,y−yj) itself that I misunderstand.